# plot dataframs based on rows values in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have dataframes dataset of two users (userA, userB) as follows:

Each user's dataframe has size is (50,158) where 50 is # of rows (i.e., samples) and 158 is # of columns (i.e, features).

I want to plot each row of the userA in a separated horizontal line with blue color such that the x-axis ranges from 0~158 (i.e., index of feature) and y-axis is the value. So 50 horizontal blue lines represent the 50 rows of userA. Similarly the another red and horizontal represent the 50 rows of userB.
Both 100 lines should be on the same figure.

## This is the updated code:

```
def plot_features(userA, userB):
    ax = userA.T.plot(color='b', label='userA')
    userB.T.plot(color='r', label='userB', ax =ax)
    plt.xlabel('Index of the features', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('Values', fontsize=18)
    plt.legend(loc='lower left')
    ax.set_title('Plotting features of UserA and UserB', fontsize=16)
    plt.show()
```

## This is the output:

[image]

How I can fix the legend?

Comment: Can you show an example ? Give a data frame with values and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
ax = dfA.T.plot(color='b')
dfB.T.plot(color='r', ax=ax)

# legend handler
h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend([h[0], h[50]], ['UserA', 'UserB'])
```

Output (my toy dataframes have 5 rows):

[image]

Comment: I updated the code in the question based on your answer. It works fine but still has a legend problem. Could you help with this?

Comment: You forgot `legend=False` inside `plot()`

Comment: But, I need to put the legend!!

Comment: What do you want the legend look like? You don't expect to have 50 x 2 lines in it do you?

Comment: I need to add a legend in the corner: red legend for userB and blue legend for userA